# Keep Notification Area open on outside click

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a `Dialog`, that is displayed on top of the `NotificationArea` and interacting with the `Dialog` does not close NotificationArea. The good example illustrating what I want is `BubbleUPNP` application available on Play Store.

[image: BubbleUPNP screenshot]

So when I click the marked buttons, the dialog shows up and I'm able to interact dialog as well as Notification at the same time.

So, what I've tried:

I've created a `Notification` and set a `PendingIntent` on one of it's buttons

```
Intent volumeUpIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationButtonListener.class);
volumeUpIntent.setAction("setVolume");

PendingIntent pendingVolumeUpIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, volumeUpIntent, 0);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.volumeIBtn, pendingVolumeUpIntent);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
builder.setAutoCancel(false);
builder.setOngoing(true);
builder.setContentInfo(getResources().getText(R.string.drag_to_expand));
notification = builder.build();

mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notification.bigContentView = remoteView;
notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
mNM.notify(1, notification);
```

Then I've created a `BroadcastListener`, which catches `Notification`'s actions:

```
public static class NotificationButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("setVolume")) {

            Intent volumeIntent = new Intent(context, VolumeActivity.class);
            volumeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(volumeIntent);    

        }
```

When I click the button in `Notification`, the `Activity` themed as `Dialog` shows up, but when I try to interact the `Dialog`, `NotificationArea` closes. Any suggestions, how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Just to double check where the problem is: as your pendingintent resolves to a broadcast the notification area should stay open. Does that work without the Dialog in your case? So if you don't show a dialog the drawer stays open?

Comment: I open the notification, press the button, Dialog is displayed, but it's kinda "under" the notification layer, so when I try to interact with the Dialog (click outside Notification Area), Notification Area collapses.

Comment: The question was if the notification area stays open if you don't display a dialog. I presume that is the case. Probably your dialog steels the focus so your notification is collapsed. You could try  to use android:focusable="false" and android:focusableInTouchMode="false" on the layout of your dialog activity - but it is just a guess.

Comment: No, you didn't understood the initial question correctly. When I display dialog NotificationArea is not collapsed, it collapses when I try to interact with the dialog.

Comment: I really think the behavior you want is not possible, IMO that is why `addAction()` is possible on notifications along with custom layouts and `PenginIntent`.

Comment: I thought it too, but then I've found BubbleUPNP app (see the screenshots), which implementet that kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code, that worked for me:

```
        alertDialogLayout = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.volume_dialog, null);    

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = new LayoutParams();
        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        wmlp.width = dm.widthPixels / 5;
        wmlp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        wmlp.y += 10;
        wmlp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        wmlp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
        wm.addView(alertDialogLayout, wmlp);
```

This displayed the view on top of all opened activities and notification area and allowed me to interact with the view's elements.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use WindowManager to add your control view. I think the window type you are looking for is `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

See [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html), [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: I looked up BubbleUPNP and they aren't using a `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission, so perhaps there is another way to accomplish this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` does not allow to interacti with the elements on the view, it just displays the view on top of everything.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog (an activity in fact) would have to be defined as non-modal so it allows clicks to the background instead of being dismissed. You can achieve that using the following code right after `super.onCreate(...)` and before `setContentView(...)`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Remember that you need to implement some other way how to close the dialog. I would use a timeout which would be reset anytime an action (notification button pressed, anything inside dialog pressed) occured.

**More reading:**
[FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL),
[FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH)

Comment: It works, if I have activity and dialog themed activity on top. Then I'm able to interact both dialog and activity under, but in this case - the dialog is under the notification and I can't get it on top of it.